# React delete list of component with button

Tags: reactjs, list, components

I insert **all different** components into an array so that last clicked component will show on the top,

but I don't know how to delete the item with a button click inside the component

It seems I can't pass the function with key index inside the component...

So I don't know which component I clicked ...

Please help me figure it out.

```
ComponentA.js
....
render(){
   return <button onClick{this.props.Delete}>Delete</button>
}
```

---

```
Parent.js
const List =({ComponentsList}) =>(
<div> 
ComponentsList.map((item,i) => <div key={i}>{item}</div>)} 
</div>)
```

---

Besides, 
I also find people don't use this way to list items,

what if these components are all different?

What will people usually deal with it?

Thanks !

.

.

.

**Edited:**

---

Figure out one question about how to delete component

see the answer below

**But I find State still exist !!!**

Can any one help me ?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my friend I find my mistake.

Maybe it is too stupid to make this kind of obvious mistake so I can find an answer on the website.

Hope it will hope someone who is a beginner and need some information when deal this kind of problem.

---

Parent.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      listState:[<ComponentB type="AAAA" delete={this.RemoveItem} />, ...]
  }
}

RemoveItem(dom) {
dom.currentTarget.parentNode.remove()
console.log("detect delete")
}


render() {
    const mapToComponent = data => {
      return data.map((contact, i) => {
        return <div>{contact}</div>
      })
    }

    return (
      <div className="Graph-Panels">
        {mapToComponent(this.state.PanelState)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I end up using filter to remove the delete components , fyi ..., if have any better solution plz let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you hold the child components in a list. You can have it in the State.

```
inputList: []
```

Let's say there's a button on the parent component to add child components. Its code will look similar to this.

```
<div>
    <Button variant= "light" className="button" onClick={this.onAddAnotherBtnClick}> 
        Add Another
    </Button>
 {this.state.inputList.map(function(input, index) {
  return input;  
 })}
 </div>
```

(You might have to bind the onAddAnotherBtnClick like this). In the state,

```
this.onAddAnotherBtnClick = this.onAddAnotherBtnClick.bind(this);
```

onAddAnotherBtnClick looks like this.

```
onAddAnotherBtnClick = (event) =>{
    const inputList = this.state.inputList;
    this.setState({
    inputList: inputList.concat(<ChildComponent Id={inputList.length} 
        callbackDeleteButton={this.delete}/>)
  });
}
```

This is the delete method.

```
delete = (Id) => {
  delete this.state.inputList[Id];  
  this.setState({ inputList : this.state.inputList });
}
```

This is the Delete button on the child component.

```
<Button variant= "light" className="button" onClick={this.onDeleteButtonClick}>
    Delete
</Button>
```

Here's the onDeleteButtonClick method.

```
onDeleteButtonClick = () => {
    this.props.callbackDeleteButton(this.state.Id);
}
```

(You'll have to bind the method in the State like this).

```
this.onDeleteButtonClick = this.onDeleteButtonClick.bind(this);
```

What happens here is that I send the ID to each child component when it's created on the props. When the child component's delete button is clicked it sends its ID to the parent through a callback method the parent has supplied.